# pass clicked value to modal by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've executed a query $viewTablo and populated a table with that, one of the areas must be clickable (see `if ($i==1)` ) and a modal must be shown with its details.

```
    while(odbc_fetch_row($viewTablo))
         {
         for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($viewTablo);$i++)
         {
         if ($i==1)
         {
             echo '
                              <td>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="text-xs text-center font-weight-bold mb-0">'.odbc_result($viewTablo,$i).'</a>             
                              </td>';
        else
       {
                    echo '
                      <td>
                        <p class="text-xs text-center font-weight-bold mb-0">'.odbc_result($viewTablo,$i).'</p>
                      </td>';  
       }  
       }
       echo '</tr>';
       }
```

A more understandable example:

[image]

every cell is `odbc_result(i)` of the fetched row. When I clicked the **a** I need to show  values **1 2 3 4 5 6** of the **a** inside the modal. Could you please help me with this? I don't know how many ways to do this but I prefer javascript.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? You need to handle the modal's shown event in JS, and write some code to retrieve the data - either by extracting it from the nearby table cells from the clicked on, or by making another AJAX request to the server to fetch that specific row data. It's unclear what you've researched, what step you've got up to in the process, or where precisely you need help. Please clarify and question and make it more specific. See also [ask]./

Comment: thanks I solved it, I was just confused about loops @ADyson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I explored:

```
 ...echo '
                      <td>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-id='.odbc_result($viewTablo,$i)
.' data-muhatapkod='.odbc_result($viewTablo,$i+1).' data-target="#exampleModal" class="modal2 text-xs text-center font-weight-bold mb-0">'.odbc_result($viewTablo,$i).'</a>             
                      </td>';

$(document).on("click", ".modal2", function () {
     var eventId = $(this).data('id');
     $('#idHolder').html( eventId );
     var eventId2 = $(this).data('muhatapkod');
     $('#idHolder2').html( eventId2 );
});

 <div class="modal-body">
       
        <input type="hidden" name="eventId" id="eventId"/>
            <span id="idHolder"></span> 
            <input type="hidden" name="eventId2" id="eventId2"/>
            <span id="idHolder2"></span>    
      </div>
```